# How to Import Signed Application in Eclipse?

Tags: android

I have made an  signed application and mailed it on my email but the other day I had to format my computer due to some virus and the code is totally lost. Can anyone suggest me how can i recover the code from signed application?

Comment: Response here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always use Java decompiler like [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) But it will take lot of efforts to get your whole application back.